# refresh TableView after clearing data source object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, caching, uitableview

The issue is when i'm trying to remove all entries in my data source object and so clear all the rows in my tableview, i'm succeeding with the first part, the counter of rows to show (`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method) returns `0`, but the cells still contain obsolete data.

(Have little reputation here to post images, so i downloaded it to ftp: [history.png](http://x-nya.ucstudio.ru/history.png))

Here's an example of what i'm trying to do. The trash bin icon clears the database, sets rows count to zero, but these cells remain in the table, which causes crashes when scrolling it.

Data source object stores as a property in AppDelegate, so ViewController gets data from there.

Here's some code:

**HistoryViewController.h**

```
@interface HistoryViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet UITableView *historyTable;
    SynonymsAppDelegate *appDelegate;
}

@property (retain) UITableView *historyTable;

- (IBAction)clearHistory:(id) sender;

@end
```

**HistoryViewController.m**

```
@implementation HistoryViewController

@synthesize historyTable;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    appDelegate = (SynonymsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate initHistoryList];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [appDelegate.historyList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    HistoryModel *historyEntry = [appDelegate.historyList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = historyEntry.word;
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)clearHistory:(id)sender {
    [HistoryDataController clearHistory]; // removes entries from DB
    [appDelegate initHistoryList]; // refreshes data source object
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // doesn't help
}
```

**AppDelegate** has `(NSMutableArray) *historyList` property and this function:

```
- (void)initHistoryList {
    HistoryDataController *historyDataController = [[HistoryDataController alloc] initWithHistoryData];
    historyList = [historyDataController.historyEntries retain];
    [historyDataController release];
}
```

I believe the problem is that TableView somehow caches the values of it's cells, but why do they display when t`ableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns `0`? And how to purge that cache?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and seeing if the numberofrows in section is actually being called?

Comment: yep, not by setting a breakpoint, though, i've been logging the calls with NSLog(); When tapping the trashbin button, 1.database clears, 2.as well as AppDelegate historyList property, 3.rowsInSection returns 0, and then nothing happens (cells stay where they are)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem definetely was in misunderstanding of TableView delegate and outlets. 
For example, `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` should be replaced with `- (NSInteger)tableView:historyTable [...]`, thus awoiding creation of TableView instance and it allows us to call `reloadData` for a proper TableView instance in our `- (IBAction)clearHistory:(id)sender` method:

```
- (IBAction)clearHistory:(id)sender {
    [HistoryDataController clearHistory];
    [appDelegate.historyList removeAllObjects];
    [appDelegate initHistoryList];
    [self.historyTable reloadData];
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the line `[self.tableView reloadData];` What you are clearing is the tableView of the UITableViewController and not the historyTable which I'm guessing you are using.

So a `[self.historyTable reloadData];` should do the trick.

Comment: No, i tried this already. Moreover, when using [self.tableView reloadData]; it calls at least tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method, and when i try [self.historyTable reloadData]; it does not. Still, maybe this's some sort of caching of table cells causes the problem?

Comment: Unless you have two table views in your view I would recommend removing historyTable and then make all connections to tableView instead. To my knowledge there is no cache like the one you are leaning towards. When you return 0 from numberOfRowsInSection the table gets cleared. An idea could be to start a new project with the navigation template, or add a new table view controller and add in the functionality one function at a time. I have found some problems like that.

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't get it. historyTable is a property (IBOutlet) of HistoryViewController (subclass of UITableViewController). What is tableView to which i should make connections? ) Still, i'll try to create this table from scratch, adding functionality little by little.

Comment: To try and clarify, UITableView controllers have an intrinsic UITableView property.  As such, there's no need to define a second one (as you've done) unless you want an additional tableview for that particular controller.  Assuming your HistoryViewController is only in charge of managing data for one tableview (the one that you're having issues with), you should just set up all your connections to the .tableView property and get rid of historyTable.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me in understanding of how UITableView works. However, that doesn't solve my issue :)

Comment: Still, that [self.tableView reloadData]; invocation in my IBAction clearHistory method updates row counter to zero and doesn't do anything with rows themselves ><

Comment: Why not take the advice that's been given by Sam and Robert and get rid of history table? That way you know that you're using only one table view and there's less things that could be wrong. I think that might help you get to the bottom of why it's not refreshing.

Comment: I mentioned that i've already done that and it didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information about your setup, I cannot be sure, but this is what I think is happening.

There are two tables in your view. UITableViewController automatically creates its own table if it is not given one by the Nib. Fix this by using the tableView property in Interface Builder and remove the historyTable property.

The dataSource property on your table is not properly set. Make sure it is set to your HistoryViewController object, or it will not know where to get the data from.

Also, you have a memory leak in your initHistoryList method. The old historyList value is not released, so it will be leaked. But why do you have to call both [HistoryDataController clearHistory] and [appDelegate initHistoryList]? Shouldn't clearing the database clear the array too? If not, you should be able to just create a new NSMutableArray in initHistoryList instead of creating and releasing a HistoryDataController.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `UITableView` IBOutlet.  If it's improperly connected, your call to `reloadData` would do nothing.

Comment: everything look good here. 'historyTable' of HistoryViewController class is connected with UITableView..